# Can the past subjunctive be an attribute?

Tags: grammar

I heard music and such lines in a song "Cheers to the wish you were here, but you're not". I know that the present subjunctive can be used as an attribute after some nouns like " Suggestion, command" And so on. As I understand, the sentence "you were here" is the past subjunctive mood in the function of an attribute clause of the word "the wish". Is it right? Can the past subjunctive be used in the function of an attributive clause? If yes, after all nouns or only some limited list of that ones?

Comment: The grammar is irrelevant here.  There is an idiom "Wish you were here"  The song is just quoting the fixed phrase.  There is absolutely no point at all in trying to analyse the grammar.  Instead imagine the lyrics are "Cheers to the *'Wish you were here'*, but you're not."

Comment: But there is no quotation marks

Comment: You should blame the transcriber for that.  You should understand the lyric as if there were.

Comment: Why are you unsure about which tag to use besides "grammar"? If you search ELL's tags for "subjunctive", for example, you'll find at least one that I think would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an idiom "Wish you were here!"  It is used on postcards sent from on holiday. It used to be the tradition that when you were on holiday somewhere you would send picture postcards to all your friends. You might sign off with "Wish you were here". I suspect that the tradition hasn't survived the Instagram age.

So the song means

> Cheers to the "Wish you were here!"...

"Wish" is a verb, and is grammatically unrelated to "Cheers to the". You could paraphrase it as

> Cheers to the fact that you said, "Wish you were here".

It is like saying

> Good luck to the "Yours sincerely" ...

Song transcriptions often miss out punctuation. These are lyrics, not formal English.